# Not to validate the form in Symfony 2

Tags: forms, symfony

Here is my form, I build in the controller:

```
    $defaulData = ....
    $formBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData);
    $entity_options = array(
        'class' => 'MyBundle:Param',
        'property' => 'description',
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->getParamsFromCategorieQueryBuilder(MyController::$category_for_list);
        },
        'label' => 'Donnée à afficher'
    );

    $formBuilder
            ->add('entity_types', 'entity', $entity_options);
```

The form is a list of Param objects, it displays good but for some reason, when I submit the form, I have an error on entity_types field saying that the value cannot be blank though there is one Param selected (even by default).

So I was wondering if I could disable validation.

When whould I put this validation_groups to false ? if it is in $entity_options, I tried it already and it does not work.

ty

Comment: Have you already see  this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#disabling-validation?

Answer (score 0):

You should modify you options like this (both require and groups are needed):

```
$entity_options = array(
    'class' => 'MyBundle:Param',
    'property' => 'description',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->getParamsFromCategorieQueryBuilder(MyController::$category_for_list);
    },
    'required' => false,
    'validation_groups' => false,
    'label' => 'Donnée à afficher'
);
```

If the error is instead on the Form class itself, you should change in:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'validation_groups' => false,
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to prevent validation for good is this one :

```
$formBuilder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $event->stopPropagation();
    }, 900);
```

It prevents from calling the validation event.

The solution that giosh94mhz gave me what not good because even with validation_group = false some validation are still done.